# SQL inner join many to many instances existance

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I have two tables

```
Campaigns ( name, date, url, etc. )
campaign_tags ( campaign_name, tag )
```

I'm trying to select all campaigns that have a list of tags, i.e

```
SELECT * 
from campaigns
inner join campaign_tags on campaigns.name=campaign_tags.name
where ( list of campaign tags ) in ( list of tags )
```

I have the list of tags (they are strings seperated by "," ), I want the campaigns that have all their tags included in that list. how can I do that?

*edit; sample data:*

`Campaign:`
`"MyCampaign", "22/11/2017","https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47431394"`
`"MyCampaign2", "22/11/2017","https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47431394"`
`CampaignTags:
"MyCampaign","sports"
"MyCampaign","stackoverflow"
"MyCampaign","Life"
"MyCampaign2","food"`

If the list im querying for is `"sports","life",stackoverflow","health","programming"` , then "MyCampaign","22/11/2017" etc. should come up, since all of its tags are included in the list, but "MyCampaign2" shouldn't; If im querying for `"food","sports"`, then "MyCampaign2" should come up, and if im querying for "sports" then nothing should come up.

Comment: Sample and expected data will be helpful to better understand your problem

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Editted with sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As variant

```
SELECT *
FROM Campaigns
WHERE name IN(
          SELECT campaign_name
          FROM campaign_tags
          WHERE tag IN("sports","life")
          GROUP BY campaign_name
          HAVING COUNT(tag)=LENGTH('"sports","life"')-LENGTH(REPLACE('"sports","life"',',',''))+1 -- count of tags
        )
```

SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8870c/10

The second variant for the new condition

```
SELECT *
FROM Campaigns
WHERE name IN(
          SELECT campaign_name
          FROM campaign_tags
          GROUP BY campaign_name
          HAVING
            COUNT(CASE
                    WHEN tag IN("sports","life","stackoverflow","health","programming")
                    THEN tag
                  END)=COUNT(tag)
        )
```

SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed1294/12

You also can use `DISTINCT` if tags can dublicate in your table

```
SELECT *
FROM Campaigns
WHERE name IN(
          SELECT campaign_name
          FROM campaign_tags
          GROUP BY campaign_name
          HAVING
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE
                    WHEN tag IN("sports","life","stackoverflow","health","programming")
                    THEN tag
                  END)=COUNT(DISTINCT tag)
        )
```

SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed1294/13

Comment: Also works, although its less intuative for me next to Khalid's answer.

Comment: `a=LENGTH('"sports","life"')` - full length of string, `b=LENGTH(REPLACE('"sports","life"',',',''))` - length without comma. `(a-b)` - count of comma. `(a-b)+1` - count of words. => `HAVING COUNT(tag)=2`

Comment: I editted the question to further clarify what im trying to ask. do you have any idea?

Comment: how do I do it with 4 tags? 6 tags? 1 tag?

Comment: For other tags you need to replace all the `"sports","life"` to your tags, for example `"sports","stackoverflow","life"` - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed1294/10 You need to put your tags to three places.

Comment: I see, I asked the question wrong. You query for tags in the campaign tags, im trying to see if the campaign tags are included in the given tags. Look at the last edit. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This should get you those campaigns who have these tags not single a single tag but all of these tags

```
SELECT c.*
FROM campaigns c
INNER JOIN campaign_tags ct ON c.name=ct.name
WHERE ct.tag IN ( "sports","life" )
GROUP BY c.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ct.tag) = SUM(ct.tag IN ( "sports","life" ))
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf8708/1)

Comment: Interesting and the most understandable of the bunch, im going to go with you. Thank you!

Comment: I unticked your solution because you can put any tag in there - i.e "s" instead of "life", and it will still select the same campaign despite "s" not being one of the tags. Any idea why / how to overcome it?

Comment: I editted the question to further clarify what im trying to ask.

Comment: @A.Abramov I don't get your point but as per the update in your question this solution is still working have a look http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf8708/5

Comment: @A.Abramov For untick answer no worries you are open to choose any answer which is working for you

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry this solution is for sqlserver only, failed to see it was for mysql. but will leave as may be useful for other. Charindex can be replaced with Locate function, however mysql does not support WITH**

The solution finds all campaigns that have all the tags in the search string

This solution has any easy to place in value that you wish to search on.

Only caveat is that no tag can contain a ','. If this can happen then need another delimiter. . Also won't accommodate duplicate tags in search string.

For the record, using a campaign_id would be nicer to do the join

```
create table c
    (
        thename varchar(100),
        thedate datetime,
        theurl  varchar(100)
    )

create table ctags
(
    thename varchar(100),
    thetag  varchar(100)
)

create unique index c_u1 on c(thename)
create unique index ctags_u1 on ctags(thename,thetag)


insert into c values ('mycampaign_good1','20170101','http://127.0.0.1')
insert into c values ('mycampaign_bad1','20170101','http://127.0.0.1')

insert into ctags values ('mycampaign_good1','sports')
insert into ctags values ('mycampaign_good1','stackoverflow')
insert into ctags values ('mycampaign_good1','programming')

insert into ctags values ('mycampaign_bad1','sports')
insert into ctags values ('mycampaign_bad1','stackoverflow')
insert into ctags values ('mycampaign_bad1','life')

/* only good1 succeeds*/
with searchstr as
(
   select 'programming,sports,stackoverflow' str
),
numvals as
(
    select len(searchstr.str) - len(replace(searchstr.str,',',''))+1 n
    from searchstr
)
select  c.thename
from c join ctags on c.thename = ctags.thename
where charindex (','+ctags.thetag,','+(select str from searchstr)) >0
group by c.thename 
having count(*) = (select numvals.n from numvals)
;
/* both succeed */
with searchstr as
(
   select 'sports,stackoverflow' str
),
numvals as
(
    select len(searchstr.str) - len(replace(searchstr.str,',',''))+1 n
    from searchstr
)
select  c.thename
from c join ctags on c.thename = ctags.thename
where charindex (','+ctags.thetag,','+(select str from searchstr)) >0
group by c.thename 
having count(*) = (select numvals.n from numvals)
;
/* both fail as neither have friends */
with searchstr as
(
   select 'friends,sports,stackoverflow' str
),
numvals as
(
    select len(searchstr.str) - len(replace(searchstr.str,',',''))+1 n
    from searchstr
)
select  c.thename
from c join ctags on c.thename = ctags.thename
where charindex (','+ctags.thetag,','+(select str from searchstr)) >0
group by c.thename 
having count(*) = (select numvals.n from numvals)
```